# axios cannot get public/[name].json folder in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

**This is my Public folder**

```
public/
   assets/
   src/
   items.json
   index.html
src/
  layout/
     Items/ items.tsx - useEffect works fine
     Overview/ Overview.tsx  - useEffect does not work
index.tsx
package.json
```

**This is my Overview.tsx**

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    function Overview(props: any): JSX.Element  {
    
        const [items, setItems] = useState([])
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get('items.json')
                .then(res => setItems(res.data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }, []);
    
        return ( 
          <div>
              //JSX Goes here
          </div>
         );
    }
```

My **Overview.tsx** have the same code with my other page but this is what I get in items.json in dev tools

**Headers**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/item/items.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Preview**

```
Cannot GET /item/items.json
```

**This is my Items.tsx** in a separate folder and this block works fine

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('items.json')
        .then(res => setItems(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, []);
```

Comment: You're probably on an `/item` page right now. You should do the request relative to your domain, like `/items.json`.

Comment: I'm fetching the data on my Public folder, My guess is to put only `axios.get('items.json')`

Comment: That is not now HTTP works, if you don't add a `/` you're doing it relative to your current path (which is `http://localhost:3000/item`)

Comment: but my **Items.tsx** works really well they have the same code and even directory. how could not my Overview.tsx failed to get the same data.

Comment: Because your Overview is probably on your root page, and your Items page isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your axios function to this:

```
axios.get('/items.json')
  .then(res => setItems(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

because you're using relative path it's going to fetch from `/currentPath/items.json`
but if you use `/items.json`, axios fetches your json file from `root/items.json`